# How do I neatly indicate an active entry in a prompt?

Tags: gui-design, dynamic-ui, prompt

I'm working on a software which shows a bunch of entries and also has to indicate that one of the entries is active. This is how my prompt looks:

[image: The prompt]

In this case, I've temporarily coloured the active entry red. I need some suggestions on how to indicate to the user that some entry is active. I'm pretty sure there must be some widely adopted convention for this.

One thing that came to my mind, was to *show a bullet symbol on the right*. But I think it might just not look okay.

Comment: I won't post an answer as it's just an initial thought, but your idea of a bullet on the right could work well if you make it green. A little green circle is quite common to indicate "online" or "currently active". Think like how chat apps indicate if someone is active. Also, the green will contrast nicely with your dark theme. That said, I think Mike's answer is a decent suggestion too... can't get much more obvious than text that explicitly says what it means!

Comment: Yeah, my  first choice would be that only. But if I fail to implement it due to Pango limitations, then I'll go for the bullet.

Answer (score 2):

You can be explicit, using a simple lozenge with text.

[image]

The *dot* indicator is commonly used to denote file that's been modified, which may not be the case for you.

Comment: Hmm, looks nice. However I doubt if it would be possible to implement using `rofi` and [Pango markup](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/pango-markup-language.html). But I do think that it's correct direction to proceed.

Comment: I personally would be inclined to play with the colour of the lozenge to help it stand out a bit more, but otherwise it's a pretty good suggestion.